# Symfony2 localization with JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Tags: php, symfony, localization

I installed with composer:

`"jms/i18n-routing-bundle": "dev-master"` and 
`"jms/translation-bundle": "1.1.*"`

Then i add them to AppKernel file

```
new JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\JMSI18nRoutingBundle(), 
new JMS\TranslationBundle\JMSTranslationBundle(),
```

After that I add this at the end of config.yml

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [de, en]
    strategy: prefix
```

Finally I have boundle with simply controller.

```
namespace Comflex\W2Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Comflex\W2Bundle\Models;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        $user = NULL;
        if($session->get('user')!== NULL){
            $user = $session->get('user');
        }
        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', 'en');
        $locale = $request->getLocale();

        return $this->render(
             'ComflexW2Bundle:Home:index.html.twig',
             array(
                'user' => $user,
                'locale' => $locale,
                'authFormPlaceholder' => array(
                    'login' => $this->get('translator')->trans('LOGIN'),
                    'password' => $this->get('translator')->trans('PASSWORD'),
                )
            )
            );
    }
}
```

**routing.yml** inside bundle

```
comflex_w2_home:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: ComflexW2Bundle:Home:index}
```

and two files with translations data (`message.de.yml` and `message.en.yml`)

When I go to `http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/de/` or `http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php` then both translation are correct, but when I add `/en` to URL then I get `No route found for "GET /en"`. How to fix it? And how to add `/en` or `/de` (dependending on the users language value) everytime when it's missing?

example: `http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php` -> `http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/en` when user language is **english** or `http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/de` when language is **german**.

Answer (score 1):

1. if you change the strategy of jms_i18n settings you need to manually clear your cache. so i think it's still working with **prefix_except_default** instead of just **prefix**
2. in your routing.yml

> 

```
front.nolang:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Default:nolang }
    options: { i18n: false }

front.index:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
    options: { i18n: true }
```

this to have two different routes, the first (just /) will do a redirect to the right route with something like this

> ```
> public function nolangAction(Request $request){
>     $locale = $request->getLocale();
>     //...add your checks here
>     return $this->redirectToRoute('front.index',['_locale' => $locale]);
> }
> ```

PS. i did it long time ago so i'm not sure if all works fine now, please confirm